# Database vs Files For Stock Market Filters

Tags: database, csv

I've stock market data. Each file is named after the company and contains basic attributes like OHLCV, Date, etc.

I want  to create a scanner, for example:

> Get a list of stocks where open > 50 && market_cap > 100000

This would return a list of companies that specify the given conditions.

Now the question: Should I use a `database` or keep the data as `csv` files.

Queries in approach:

**Database**

How many tables should I make? Is one table per company is good? I say yes and I follow this strategy then for example when I want a list of companies with `open price` > 20, I have to query the latest row from each and every table. Won't it be better to have `date-wise` tables in such a case? How to decide?

**Files**

I created new files which contain names of the company sector-wise. So each file is named after a sector, for example, IT. the file `IT.csv` will have the names of all the companies which belong to that sector.

I've to implement both the mentioned cases, but I am not able to decide the better approach. Which factors should I consider?

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to have a database for this type of queries, otherwise you will end up writing file crawlers each time you want to extract data.

If you place all of the items in one table, and add a column for the company, you will have the advantage of running global queries (ex. find company that is positive 3 days in a row, find who was in top 10 on a date, etc.).

Also you might think about which indexes to add to the table to speed up the extraction.

Answer (score 0):

Your data appears to be a good fit for a relational database. It has predefined rows and columns, and the data is not binary formatted.

I'm not sure what a "scanner" is, but the sample query you gave is perfect for a SQL statement.

The common way to model this is to store data that belongs to a logical entity type in a single table. In your case, you might have:

```
stock_events
-------------
id (primary key)
event_date (datetime)
stock_symbol (string)
open_price (decimal)
market_cap (decimal)
....
```

Your query can then be written as:

```
select * 
from stock_events
where open_price > 50
and   market_cap > 50000
and event_date = ?
```

Your challenges would become index creation - your queries are likely to be ad hoc, so hard to optimize in advance. You're also likely to need queries that compare one stock against itself over time, or against others over time.

For this, you'd need to learn a fair amount of SQL.

The alternative is to analyze this data using tools like R or Python's big data tooling (pandas). The benefit here is that you can learn from a lot of pre-existing examples (e.g. Kaggle), but the learning curve can be steep.